# Как создать Docker контейнер для работы скрипта на Python?

Tags: python, selenium, docker, exe, dockerfile

Мне нужно создать **Docker** файл для моего скрипта на Python, который состоит из файлов `.py`,     виртуального окружения и `.exe` файла необходимого для работы скрипта.
Суть скрипта - скрипт используется для парсинга на Selenium, поэтому для работы необходим файл драйвера `chormedriver.exe`. В контейнер это нужно обернуть, чтобы скрипт мог работать на нужном мне хостинге.

Вот код который у меня есть:

```
# Код из .py файла, где используется chromedriver.exe
global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(f"https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/{id}/feedbacks?imtId={imt_id}")
time.sleep(5)
big_stat = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="rating-product__numb")
```

Код **Dockerfile**, который мне посоветовали написать:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false -o Acquire::Check-Date=false update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev python-distribute
RUN alias python=python3
RUN echo "alias python=python3" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN apt-get -qy --no-install-recommends install \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    wget \
    curl \
    libxi6 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    vim \
    xvfb \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get -qy --no-install-recommends install \
     $(apt-cache depends firefox | grep Depends | sed "s/.*ends:\ //" | tr '\n' ' ') \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && cd /tmp \
  && wget --no-check-certificate -O firefox-esr.tar.bz2 \
    'https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-esr-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US' \
  && tar -xjf firefox-esr.tar.bz2 -C /opt/ \
  && ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox \
  && rm -f /tmp/firefox-esr.tar.bz2

RUN set -e
RUN echo "Starting X virtual framebuffer (Xvfb) in background..."
RUN Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
RUN export DISPLAY=:99
RUN exec "$@"

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get -qy --no-install-recommends install python3.8
RUN rm /usr/bin/python3
RUN ln -s python3.8 /usr/bin/python3

RUN export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
RUN echo "export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8" >> ~/.bashrc

COPY sbase /SeleniumBase/sbase/
COPY seleniumbase /SeleniumBase/seleniumbase/
COPY examples /SeleniumBase/examples/
COPY integrations /SeleniumBase/integrations/
COPY requirements.txt /SeleniumBase/requirements.txt
COPY setup.py /SeleniumBase/setup.py
RUN find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
RUN find . -name __pycache__ -delete
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools-scm
RUN cd /SeleniumBase && ls && pip3 install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
RUN cd /SeleniumBase && pip3 install .

RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.31.0/geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN chmod +x geckodriver
RUN mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
RUN wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN chmod +x chromedriver
RUN mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/

COPY integrations/docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /
COPY integrations/docker/run_docker_test_in_firefox.sh /
COPY integrations/docker/run_docker_test_in_chrome.sh /
RUN chmod +x *.sh
COPY integrations/docker/docker_config.cfg /SeleniumBase/examples/
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно создать Docker файл, при помощи которого на сервере будет работать Selenium

Comment: Я вам рекомендую воспользоваться официальным образом https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#quick-start. Если вы все же хотите создать сами, то я рекомендую посмотреть, как это делается в официальном образе. Во-вторых, расскажите, что не работает. Какие ошибки получаете и т.д.? Без этого вам скорее всего не помогут. Далее, *.exe файл внутри докера вы не запустите, в докере linux - там нужен бинарник для линукса. Опять же смотрите Dokerfile-ы оф. образа, откуда его берут и что делают https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/NodeChrome/Dockerfile